# Powershell Function SQL Stored Procedure with Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, csv

The error received is "The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlCommand objects." & "Procedure or function 'usp__SingleUpdateServerBackupPath' expects parameter '@decServerName', which 
was not supplied."
PowerShell code:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 1.0

function update-serverbackuppath {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeLine=$True)][object[]]$inputobject
)
BEGIN {
    $connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $connection.ConnectionString = "server=servername;database=database;trusted_connection=yes"
    $connection.Open()
}
PROCESS {

    $UpdateBackupPath = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $UpdateBackupPath.Connection = $connection
    $UpdateBackupPath.CommandText = "usp__SingleUpdateServerBackupPath"
    $UpdateBackupPath.Commandtype = [System.Data.Commandtype]::StoredProcedure

    $ParamUpdateBackupPath = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    $ParamUpdateBackupPath.ParameterName = "@decBackupPath"
    $ParamUpdateBackupPath.SqlDbType = [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar
    $ParamUpdateBackupPath.Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
    $ParamUpdateBackupPath.Value = $inputobject.paths

    $ParamUpdateBackupPathServerName = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $ParamUpdateBackupPathServerName.ParameterName = "@decServerName"
    $ParamUpdateBackupPathServerName.SqlDbType = [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar
    $ParamUpdateBackupPathServerName.Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
    $ParamUpdateBackupPathServerName.Value = $inputobject.names

    $UpdateBackupPath.Parameters.Add($ParamUpdateBackupPath)
    $UpdateBackupPath.Parameters.Add($ParamUpdateBackupPathServerName)

    $reader = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = $UpdateBackupPath.ExecuteReader()

}
END {
    $connection.Close()
}
}
```

SQL Procedure:

```
Create Procedure usp__SingleUpdateServerBackupPath
(
@decBackupPath AS varchar(50),
@decServerName AS varchar(50)
)
AS
UPDATE BCKP
SET PTH = @decBackupPath
FROM BCKP
INNER JOIN SRVR
    ON SRVR.ID = BCKP.FK_SRVR
WHERE SRVR.NM = @decServerName
```

CSV File Format

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Bin\Repos\Backup.csv | C:\Bin\Scripts\update-serverbackuppath.ps1
Names    Paths
Server1  \\fileshare\server_name
```

Comment: So what's the error message you got? It's kind of hard to try and guess the problem without it; could be anything from user rights issue to simple syntax error.

Comment: There was no error and no change in the db. My apologies for the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Powershell code has several syntax errors, like referring to enums in erroneus a way:

```
# Incorrect form
[System.Data.Commandtype.StoredProcedure]
# Correct form for referring to enumeration
[System.Data.Commandtype]::StoredProcedure
```

Later on, there is an undeclared object which's member method is called:

```
# $command is not set, so ExecuteReader method is available
$reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
```

It is highly recommended to [use strict mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692.aspx) in Powershell. It helps catching typos by preventing access to non-existing properties an uninitialized variables.

**Edit**

After the updated code, there are still two errors:

```
# This doesn't make sense. The variable should be SqlParameter, not SqlCommand
$ParamUpdateBackupPathServerName = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
# Like so:
$ParamUpdateBackupPathServerName = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter

# This is nonsense syntax
$reader = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = $UpdateBackupPath.ExecuteReader()
# Like so:
$reader = $UpdateBackupPath.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: New-Object -TypeName seems to only except fully qualified .net class names in the format System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand and intellisense in PowerShell ISE seems to understand it. I changed all of the other .net references and added Strictmode. I also changed the reference from $command to $UpdateBackupPath. I still did not receive an error message and it did not update the database.

Comment: @traggicrabbit Edit your post and add the changed code for further review.

Comment: Thank you for the clue. I am new to posting questions for help.